# How to combine rows in pandas with matching dates while not combining the values in the rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I was working on a simple python program for fun but got stuck trying to export the data to a CSV file. Right now when running `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)` it outputs a CSV file similar to this. I'm using `index=False` to avoid having strange columns randomly appearing in the CSV.

| Date | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/31/21 | 3 | nan | nan |
| 3/31/21 | 5 | 4 | nan |
| 3/31/21 | nan | nan | 3 |
| 4/1/21 | nan | nan | 6 |
| 4/1/21 | 4 | 3 | 3 |

I'm looking for an output that essentially pushes all the values upwards while still respecting the original date they were in. Something like this would be the ideal output of the previous table.

| Date | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/31/21 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 3/31/21 | 5 | nan | nan |
| 4/1/21 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| 4/1/21 | nan | nan | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [**`groupby('Date')`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [**`dropna()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) in each group's columns
2. [**`dropna()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) where columns `a`/`b`/`c` are all empty

```py
def collapse(group):
    return group.apply(lambda col: pd.Series(col.dropna().values))

df = df.groupby('Date').apply(collapse).dropna(how='all', subset=['a', 'b', 'c'])

#       Date    a    b    c
# 0  3/31/21    3    4    3
# 1  3/31/21    5  NaN  NaN
# 3   4/1/21    4    3    6
# 4   4/1/21  NaN  NaN    3
```

```py
df.to_csv('collapse.csv', index=False)

# Date,a,b,c
# 3/31/21,3.0,4.0,3.0
# 3/31/21,5.0,,
# 4/1/21,4.0,3.0,6.0
# 4/1/21,,,3.0
```

---

#### If there are only leading `nan`

You can [**`shift()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) each group's columns by their [**`first_valid_index()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html):

```py
shifted = df.groupby('Date').transform(
    lambda x: x.shift(x.index[0] - x.first_valid_index())
).dropna(how='all')

df = df[['Date']].merge(shifted, left_index=True, right_index=True)

#       Date    a    b    c
# 0  3/31/21    3    4    3
# 1  3/31/21    5  NaN  NaN
# 3   4/1/21    4    3    6
# 4   4/1/21  NaN  NaN    3
```

Comment: The first method you suggested worked. My only problem now is that after I save the csv and reopen it to make an additional entry, it shifts the older entries back.

For example, if I was to add two more values to the `c` column, while it had the same date as the `a` or `b` columns, the `c` column would be at the top of the csv while the `a` and `b` would be two rows down from the top, even with the same date.

Comment: @Beeanerd The previous answer just displayed the results without saving back to `df`. I edited the answer to save permanently like `df = df.groupby(...`. I tested saving that `to_csv()` and it's working on my end.

Comment: My issue is that my first entry will formats correctly when I save, but when I start the program again to add a new entry, it treats the previous entry as a separate date and moves it down by two rows(from row 0 it would go to 2) and adds the new entry in the newly freed rows, even if they are data existing in separate columns. I'll try to demonstrate, I apologize for the formatting.

`Date|a|b|c` (next line) `|3/31/21|3|4|NaN|` Now this saves properly, but when I reopen and add a new entry it turns into `Date|a|b|c`(next line)`3/31/21|NaN|NaN|5` (I added the 5)(next line)`|3/31/21|3|4|NaN|`

Comment: I'm thinking it may be recognizing one as a date(I think that's a pandas object type?) and the other as a string(the new one) so they might not be recognized as identical, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Beeanerd Sorry I'm having a hard time understanding. Maybe you can post a series of code lines that will reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I figured it out thank you. The saves csv was being read in as a Datetime datatype instead of a string so they weren't being grouped together causing the values to shift each other out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think in something like this:

```
new = df.groupby("Date").transform(lambda x: sorted(x, key = lambda y: y == "Empty"))

df[['a','b','c']] = new
df = df[(new != "Empty").any(1)]
```

**Output**

```
df
      Date      a      b      c
0  3/31/21      3      4      3
1  3/31/21      5  Empty  Empty
3   4/1/21      4      3      6
4   4/1/21  Empty  Empty      3
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in my question. I meant the cells were empty so I suppose `nan` would have been the appropriate filler.

Comment: @Beeanerd just change "Empty" by np.nan